# VB.NET DataGridView Cell Serial Number regenerate

Tags: vb.net, serialization, datagridview

May be this question is not much important for you but I am facing problem in this. I have a DataGridView in which I add rows by.....

```
If Me.Dgv.Rows.Count = 0 Then
    SlNo = 1
Else
    SlNo = Me.Dgv.Rows.Count + 1
End If

Me.Dgv.Rows.Add(SlNo, ItemId, ItemName, Qty, ItemRate, Amt)
```

and the rows display like...

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  Sl No  |  Item Id  |  Item Name  |  Qty  |  Rate  |  Amount  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    1    |     6     |  Item6      |  10   |  100.00|   1000.00|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    2    |     8     |  Item8      |  10   |  200.00|   2000.00|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    3    |     2     |  Item2      |  10   |  300.00|   3000.00|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    4    |     16    |  Item16     |  10   |  400.00|   4000.00|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I want to clear `Row (Sl No. - 2)` but I want to maintain the serial numbers like below.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  Sl No  |  Item Id  |  Item Name  |  Qty  |  Rate  |  Amount  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    1    |     6     |  Item6      |  10   |  100.00|   1000.00|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    2    |     2     |  Item2      |  10   |  300.00|   3000.00|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    3    |     16    |  Item16     |  10   |  400.00|   4000.00|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

or I want to clear `Row (Sl No. - 1)` and want to maintain the serial numbers like

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  Sl No  |  Item Id  |  Item Name  |  Qty  |  Rate  |  Amount  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    1    |     8     |  Item8      |  10   |  200.00|   2000.00|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    2    |     2     |  Item2      |  10   |  300.00|   3000.00|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    3    |     16    |  Item16     |  10   |  400.00|   4000.00|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

It means I want to delete/clear a row from `DataGridView` maintaining the serial numbers.

I tried like....

```
    Private Sub DgvAutoSerialNumbering()
    Dim SlNumber As Integer = 0
    If Me.Dgv.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        SlNumber = 1
    ElseIf Me.Dgv.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.Dgv.Rows.Count - 1
            SlNumber = Me.Dgv.Rows.Count
            Me.Dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = SlNumber
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

But failed to get the output.

How could I do this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found my answer. Sorry for the post.

While searching in DataGridView events, I found an event `RowPrePaint` and just three lines of code of this event solved the problem.

```
Private Sub Dgv_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles Dgv.RowPrePaint
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Me.Dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = e.RowIndex + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for viewing my post and also sorry for wasting your valuable time by missing the `event`.

Answer (score 1):

`DataGridView.RowPrePaint` event will be raised every time when `datagridview` must be repainting.
This will happened for example when you drag over `datagridview` another form or `MessageBox`
or when you minimize/hide `form` and reopen it again...

In your case you need update `Serial No` only after count of the rows was changed.

```
'Method looping all rows and update value of `Sl No` column based on index of row
Private Sub Dgv_RowCountChanged()
    For Each dgvr As DataGridViewRow in Me.Dgv.Rows
        dgvr.Cells(0).Value = dgvr.Index + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Method `Dgv_RowCountChanged` will be executed in the event handlers of `RowsAdded` and `RowsRemoved`

```
Private Sub Dgv_RowsAdded(object sender, 
                          DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e) Handles Dgv.RowsAdded
    Me.DgvCountChanged()
End Sub

Private Sub Dgv_RowsRemoved(object sender, 
                          DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e) Handles Dgv.RowsRemoved
    Me.DgvCountChanged()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to create a Column index autogenerate serial number of each row:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="~/data/commands/cancel.gif"
                      DeleteImageUrl="~/data/commands/delete.gif" DeleteText="Verwijder" EditImageUrl="~/data/commands/edit.gif"
                      EditText="Bewerk" SelectImageUrl="~/data/commands/download.gif" SelectText="Download bestand"
                      ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" UpdateImageUrl="~/data/commands/save.gif"
                      UpdateText="Opslaan">

        <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />

    </asp:CommandField>

    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nr." ReadOnly="true">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="1%" />
    </asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
```

Then on the codebehing:

```
protected void gridLidDocument_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){  
    if (e.Row.RowType.Equals(DataControlRowType.DataRow)){
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "" + ((((GridView)sender).PageIndex * ((GridView)sender).PageSize) + (e.Row.RowIndex + 1));
    }
}
```